# Is there a difference in time complexity of the "in" operator for strings compared to lists?

Tags: python, string, list, time-complexity, in-operator

I was wondering if there is any benefit to searching for a string in a list compared to searching for a substring in a string using the "in" operator.

I have always checked for a substring using the following:

```py
substr in str
```

But I came across a piece of code that split the string and then performed the check.

```py
substr in str.split()
```

Is there any benefit performance-wise or other, or was this just a preference for that programmer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those do two different things. The complexity of both is O(n), but that's not really relevant because you wouldn't choose one over the other for how fast they are; you'd make the choice based on what you actually want *to do*.

```
>>> "o b" in "foo bar"  # "o b" is a substring of "foo bar"
True
>>> "o b" in "foo bar".split()  # "o b" is not an element of ["foo", "bar"]
False
```

Comment: Gotcha. But in the case where the substring is specifically a word which would be separated by white spaces, then is there any benefit to doing a split()?

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, it can be slightly different:

```
>>> "Python" in "Monty Python's Flying Circus"
True
>>> "Python" in "Monty Python's Flying Circus".split()
False
```

And from a performance point of view, split is a lot more expensive (it creates a temporary list):

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("""'Monty' in "Monty Python's Flying Circus".split() """)
0.20677191999857314
>>> timeit("""'Monty' in "Monty Python's Flying Circus" """)
0.03346360499563161
```

We could also probably argue that if the word you're looking for is near the beginning of the sentence, the `sub in str` will be a best case scenario in O(1) (the in operation is probably coded with C's strstr); while the `sub in str.split()` will still have to split the whole text before starting to look for the word (so best-case scenario is always at least O(n), more memory consuming, etc.).